# Does "num" use more resources than "int" in dart language?

Tags: dart, numbers

I need to know if I always use "num" instead of "int" or "double" when I declare a variable is it bad for memory usage in Dart?

Is there any difference in terms of effective memory usage for these declarations in Dart?

```
num year = 1988;
num len = 181.45;

int year = 1988;
double len = 181.45;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe!

If the compiler can determine that the value is always an `int` anyway, it probably doesn't matter that you typed it as `num`.
If it cannot detect that, then it may not apply optimizations special to `int` or `double` (like unboxed values internally in a function).

The more important question is what you're trying to achieve by using `num` instead of `int` or `double`?
Will the people maintaining your code be happy, when they don't actually know if it's an `int` or `double`?

You can't use a `num` as an array index, that has to be an `int`, so generally you should use `int` for things that actually are `int`s.

It's more questionable whether you should always used `double` instead of `num` for things that are (probably, almost) always doubles. There are very few places where a `double` is required, but they do exist.

So, in general, using `num` prevents you from using the value in a place which requires an `int` or `double` (without calling `.toInt()` or `.toDouble()` first). That's the best reason to use the more precise type.

Performance should only matter if you've identified the code as a performance hot-spot.